# Does the first line of triple-quoted string impact indentation?

Tags: string, julia

I am trying to understand the rules of Julia's triple-quoted strings. From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/strings/#Triple-Quoted-String-Literals-1):

> Triple-quoted strings are also dedented to the level of the least-indented line. This is useful for defining strings within code that is indented.

I expected this:

```
println("""first
             second
             third""")
```

to print this:

```
first
  second
  third
```

Instead, I got this:

```
first
second
third
```

Does the rule quoted from the documentation exclude the first line?

Comment: I have opened an issue for this https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/25592.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. Looking at *julia-parser.scm*:
1. Julia first dedents a string *ignoring* the indentation of text directly after `"""`
2. Then strips leading newline if present.

Which means that:

```
julia> print("""  aaa
         bb
         cc""")
  aaa
bb
cc
```

and although all lines have two spaces of indentation the first is ignored and the rest is dedented.

Comment: Do you know if this is the intended behavior of triple-quoted strings? If so, should the documentation be updated to reflect this nuance?

Comment: exactly - that is what I have posted in the issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/25592. We either need to change the behavior or change the documentation :).

Comment: and it seems we will go for an update of the documentation.